# Is there an online application simulator somewhere?

Tags: windows, simulation

I've developed some Java applications and wrapped them in exe files, some of them require JDIC files, the apps run on Windows systems, since my PC is all setup for development, it has all the necessary parts, but if a user downloads and runs my apps, they may not work as I thought. So I wonder if there is any place online that I can upload my apps and try to run them in a Windows environment and see if they work in the simulation ?

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [VirtualPC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx). You can get licensing for free.

Also you can get images from MS site for various versions of Windows to test with - supposedly for browser compatibility but you can use them for other things (which may or may not violate the EULA).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [VMWare Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/).  You can get licensing for free.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Amazon's EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instances to get easy access to virtual Windows machines.  There is a bit of set up involved, but once you've done that you can spin up new machines easily enough.  There are a number of tutorials online.

However, doing it locally with virtual windows instances is going to be even easier.  I'd second VMware workstation or player.

You can download trial Windows server images directly from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a4fbe2f3-45dd-46bf-8747-16a111c04107&displaylang=en) for free.